# Firebase Collection Stream to BigQuery Transform Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

the firebase extension "Stream Collections to BigQuery" allows for configuring a Transform Function for converting the Firestore Data Json to explicit BigQuery table fields.
https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-bigquery-export

Can anyone point me to an example function or detailed docs for such functions?

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transform Function should be an [HTTP Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) with the following logic (get the input object from the request, transform it, send it back in the response) as shown in the below CF skeleton:

```js
exports.bqTransform = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    
   const inputPayload = req.body // JS Object
   // ...
   // Transform the object 
   // ...
   const outputPayload = {...}   // JS Object
    
   res.send(outputPayload);
    });
```

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-bigquery-export), the `inputPayload` object (i.e. `req.body`) contains a `data` property (which is an array) which contains a representation of the Firestore document, has shown below:

```
{ 
  data: [{
    insertId: int;
    json: {
      timestamp: int;
      event_id: int;
      document_name: string;
      document_id: int;
      operation: ChangeType;
      data: string;  // <= String containing the stringified object representing the Firestore document data
    },
  }]
}
```

The transformation implemented in your code shall create an object with the same structure (`outputPayload` in our skeleton example above) where the `data[0].json` property is adapted according to your transformation requirements.

---

Here is a very simple example in which we totally change the content of the Firestore record with some static data.

```js
exports.bqTransform = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    const inputPayload = req.body; 
    const inputData = inputPayload.data[0];

    const outputPayload = [{
        insertId: inputData.insertId,
        json: {
            timestamp: inputData.json.timestamp,
            event_id: inputData.json.event_id,
            document_name: inputData.json.document_name,
            document_id: inputData.json.document_id,
            operation: inputData.json.operation,
            data: JSON.stringify({ createdOn: { _seconds: 1664983515, _nanoseconds: 745000000 }, array: ["a1", "a2"], name: "Transformed Name" })
        },
    }]   

    res.send({ data: outputPayload });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Renaud Tarnec. That did the job!

Comment: Hi,
as a follow-up querstion: Is it recommended to use a Transform Function for extracting firestore data from json and create new fields in the data set? When I try to, I see log messages such as "Retried to insert 1 row(s) of data into BigQuery (ignoring unknown columns)"
Better to extract data from JSON at query time or how to solve the unkown column issue?

Comment: Can anyone help with translating this function to python? I'm wondering what, if anything, should the function return? Should I send something via https_fn.Response() before returning something else?